# Does `.git` directory get shared?

Tags: git

is `.git` directory local or shared directory?

There's config files I want to change but don't want to share.

google won't answer me.

Comment: The `.git` folder *is* the repository. When you push *changes*, the files come from inside `.git`. You can have a full repo without any files in your working directory and still be able to push, pull, etc. Are you confusing the working directory with the repository itself perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "Does the .git folder get added to the repository?" then the answer is **no**. The `.git` folder is local to that specific checked out location and is not part of the repository that is shared.

Comment: Ehm, the `.git` folder **is** the repository. Other files are added *to* it. There's no "checked out location" as there would be in eg SVN. It's a full repository cloned from some other repository. The working directory's files come from that `.git` folder, not some other repo

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of that, but I'm not sure that the OP is aware of that. By _checked out location_ I meant the location where the repository is cloned to. You could have another clone in a different location and have a different `.git` folder. Yes, the `.git` folder is the repository, but it is also more - it 's where the local configuration goes, the local pre and post commit hooks...

Comment: @Abizem that's what `repository` means, it's not just the data files.

Answer (score 0):

To me this question doesn't have any sense.

`.git` folder is a folder like others (but will keep all repository files) so, is it shared or local? It depends: it could be local if you (or your team buddies) have different locations for the repo. It could be shared if all of you point at the same physical resource.

Answer (score 0):

`.git` is a **Local** folder which contains all the repository data + your local config per repository.

The folder does not pushed to the server and cannot be accessed outside of your repo (of course you can use it as network path but this is not the question)

---

By the way, there was a security issue with the folder name which was fixed.
The bug was that you could rename the folder in any anme combination (came casee) and this way you can "share" and expose your .git folder.

http://git-blame.blogspot.co.il/2014/12/git-1856-195-205-214-and-221-and.html

[image]

---

#### Exception:

If using the `git new-workdir` command its "creating" the same repo under a new location. git does it by using a symbolic link to the original git folder.

[image]